# How to use the :undolist feature in vim?

Tags: vim

After making a couple of changes in an xml file opened in Vim I pressed `:undolist`  and got the following output. Is there any way I can see the actual changes? Also what is the difference between *number* and *changes* columns? I see the numbers are always the same.

```
 number changes  time
         2       2  10 seconds ago
```

Comment: The plugin [gundo](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3304) gives a visual representation of the undolist.

Comment: Very similar to [How is VIM's undo tree used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1088864).

Answer (score 4):

if you `:h undolist`, difference between number and changes is explained. in short, number is a sequence number, changes are how many changes were made on that leaf.

If you want to go back to a earlier state, you could check `:h earlier`

I recommend a very nice undo plugin:  https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim  with this you could view the states in history, without really applying them, until you find the right state.

Comment: +1. Gundo.vim is a great plugin to transverse history especially with persistent_undo. If you are more of a visual learner there is a nice vimcasts about undo branching: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/undo-branching-and-gundo-vim/

Comment: Or use the alternative [undotree.vim - Display your undo history in a graph](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4177) plugin; it does not require Python like _Gundo_.