# What can you do in Vim's visual mode that you can't do in command mode, and vice versa?

Tags: vim

I've learnt to use marks and registers in Vim to select and operate on selections of text, and now I'm starting to learn and use visual mode.

Is there any functionality that visual mode offers that isn't available in command mode, other than just the aesthetic appeal? In what scenarios would I use one over the other, and which is better to get used to by default?

Comment: Insert mode allows you to insert text, but hopefully you already know that :)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981003/what-should-i-use-vim-visual-mode-for Have you read the answer given there ?

Comment: @Luc: Ah, I didn't see that. Never mind then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help visual-start` and read sections 2, 3, 4, 5 and 7 (examples). That's not so long and really useful. Vim documentation is your first help :)